# Contributing to SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, fft, dct

I've never contributed to SciPy (or any other Python package, for that matter), but I have a super simple code that performs a 2-D discrete cosine transform using existing SciPy code for the 1-D discrete cosine transform. SciPy already has support for the 2-D (or N dimensional) fast fourier transform, but not for the 2-D discrete cosine transform. Looking at the SciPy code on GitHub, I see that most of the fourier-related code (everything in the fftpack module) is written in fortran, while the code I've put together is in Python (put together is an overstatement -- it's one line).

My question is this: I see this code as being pretty useful, and perhaps represents a good opportunity for me to contribute to SciPy. However, I definitely can't check all the boxes listed in the SciPy documentation regarding contributing code (e.g., I don't have "test units", nor do I really know what that is). How do I proceed in the process of contributing?

```
def dct2(x):
    """
    x is a 2-D numpy array
    """
    x = np.asarray(x, dtype=float)
    return fftpack.dct(fftpack.dct(x).T).T

def idct2(x):
    x = np.asarray(x, dtype=float)
    return fftpack.idct(fftpack.idct(x.T).T)
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this question doesn't presents any programming problem and so it is off topic. How ever all the best Dean.

Comment: The [contributing guidelines](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/hacking.html) might help.

Comment: Ask at the [scipy developer's mailing list](http://mail.scipy.org/mailman/listinfo/scipy-dev).

Comment: Btw, the only code I see is 2 one-liners, heavily relying on `fftpack`. Do I miss something? Because I can hardly call this a contribution.

Comment: Thank you for your input. @Evert, I guess the code I present is an example to show how one computes the 2-D DCT -- you just take the 1-D DCT of the columns of the original matrix, and then the DCT of the rows of the resulting matrix.